# An explicit example of an invariant halfspace of the unilateral shift?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces, operator-theory, operator-algebras

In a recent talk, A. Popov stated the following [fact](http://temple.birs.ca/~12w5019/Popov.pdf)

> The unilateral shift on $\ell^2$ has invariant halfspaces.

Halfspaces are closed subspaces whose dimension and codimension are both infinite.

He did not prove it. I know that unilateral shift has many invariant halfspaces, but all the examples I know are finite dimensional. Thus I wonder whether somebody can give an explicit invariant halfspace of the unilateral shift.

Just to be precise, I am asking about the forward shift, that is, $Se_n=e_{n+1}$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naturally, we should use the [Beurling theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beurling%E2%80%93Lax_theorem) on invariant subspaces. Let $\theta$ be an infinite [Blaschke product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product). The space of functions of the form $\theta f$, $f\in H^2(\mathbb D)$, is infinite dimensional and also has infinite codimension. The former is obvious and the latter is because you can knock out the zeros of $\theta$ one by one.

I'm not sure if this qualifies as an explicit example. The criteria that make an example  explicit were not made explicit.

Comment: Well, I like your answer and I know Beurling's is like the ultimate answer to all kinds of problems concerning invariant spaces of shifts. But I am hoping to see something more 'elementary', like some examples involving only sequences.

Comment: @HuiYu Chances are that if the speaker had an example in terms of sequences that could be easily described, he would have put it on the slide.

Comment: Haha~~That's true! Thanks!